# Query and list strings not found within file directory

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file with a four headings, the most important being the IP address. What I need to do is search through a file certain file directory and all of its child files and directories to see if the IP address is NOT contained within any files. If the IP address is not contained within any of the files, add the IP address to an array, and continue checking all IP addresses.  Once done, list the contents of the array.

```
$Path = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\nagios\configs\hosts"
$NotMonitoredArray = @()

$servers = Import-Csv "C:\wpg-export.csv" 
foreach ($item in $servers) {
    Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse | Where-Object {
        $_.Attributes -ne "Directory"
    } | ForEach-Object {
        if (Get-Content | Where-Object { !(Select-String -Pattern $_.IPAddress -Quiet) }) {
            $NotMonitoredArray += $_.IPAddress
        }
    }
}
```

It is getting stuck at the `Get-Content` cmdlet specifically saying

> cmdlet Get-Content at command pipeline position 1
>   Supply values for the following parameters:
>   Path[0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-Content` has a mandatory parameter `-Path` that you didn't specify. That's what's causing the error you observed. However, since `Select-String` can read files by itself you don't need `Get-Content` in the first place. Also, you definiteley want to avoid reading files from an entire directory tree multiple times. Instead create a regular expression from the IP addresses in your CSV:

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'C:\wpg-export.csv'
$pattern = ($csv | ForEach-Object {
             '({0})' -f [regex]::Escape($_.IPAddress)
           }) -join '|'
```

use that pattern to find the unique IP addresses that are present in the files in a single run:

```
$foundIP = Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse |
           Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
           Select-String -Pattern $pattern |
           Select-Object -Expand Matches |
           Select-Object -Expand Value -Unique
```

and then use the resulting list for filtering the CSV:

```
$NotMonitoredArray = $csv | Where-Object { $foundIP -notcontains $_.IPAddress } |
                     Select-Object -Expand IPAddress
```